# Seeking feedback on my design of LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, async-await

Scenario: I have a Windows Console Application on .NET 4.5 using EF 6.1 with SQL Server 2012.

Question: I would like get some feedback which of the following LINQ expressions is the preferred way or more efficient way of loading data from the database:

```
    // Option 1: Using List<>
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList 
    {
         get { return Context.Employees.Select(e => e).ToList(); }
    }

    // Option 2: Using IList<>
    public IList<Employee> EmployeeList2
    {
         get { return Context.Employees.Select(e => e).ToList(); }
    }

    // Option 3: Using IEnumerable<>
    public IEnumerable<Employee> EmployeeList3
    {
         get { return Context.Employees.Select(e => e); }
    }

    // Option 4: Using IQueryable
    public IQueryable<Employee> EmployeeList4
    {
         get { return Context.Employees.Select(e => e); }
    }

    // Option 5: Using IQueryable & AsNoTracking()
    public IQueryable<Employee> EmployeeList5
    {
         get { return Context.Employees.Select(e => e).AsNoTracking(); }
    }

    // Option 6: Using "async/await"
    public async Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeeList6()
    {
         return await Context.Employees.Select(x => x).ToListAsync(); 
    }

   // Option 7: Using "using" statement
    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList7()
    {
         using (Context context = new Context())
         {
             return Context.Employees.Select(e => e).ToList();
         }
     }
```

Please note that I don't need EF to keep track of any changes. I simply need to get the list of Employees into memory so I can manipulate them, thus the reason I added the extension method, AsNoTracking() to Option 5.

Comment: Benchmark it yourself. There will likely be immeasurable differences. The ones that return `IEnumerable<T>` after your `Select` will be quickest because thanks to deferred execution they don't actually do anything. Also, your last "option" with `using` doesn't actually use the variable declared in the `using` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing apples and oranges. Each of the approaches you list has benefits and drawbacks, so it's impossible to answer which is the "preferred way."

Likewise, many of these examples will return immediately because they use deferred execution, so they'll technically run faster, but won't actually make your program run any faster.

But if you're just trying to get an in-memory list of all the Employees, and you don't care about change tracking, as you say, I'd prefer this:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Employee> EmployeeList
{
     get { return Context.Employees.AsNoTracking().ToList(); }
}
```

- You don't need a `.Select(e => e)`: it doesn't do anything.
- `AsNoTracking()` will give you a minor performance improvement.
- `.ToList()` ensures that the values are actually loaded into memory before the method returns.
- I personally like using `IReadOnlyCollection<>`s when I want to indicate that I'm providing something that's been loaded into memory, but I don't want to give the impression that consuming code is expected to add/remove values from the collection that I return.

Comment: Great feedback! Good to know about those points and especially about IReadOnlyCollection<>, which I was not even considering.